# Apache performance log before it dies

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to log apache performance before it gets out of memory error? I have mod_status enabled and the tool is great but I want it to run maybe every 5 minutes so that when the server dies I would know what were the processes running at that time and their CPU/memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a tool like Zabbix or Nagios to keep collecting those metrics.

Also take a look at Datadog, which offers a "very easy to set up" (but paid) solution to collect, visualize, and correlate this metric.

The point is to continously collect any related metrics, and when something bad happens, it helps you to pinpoint the root of the problems by correlating data (in this case, for example server load, and traffic served by apache)

Comment: Is the data available 1 day before apache dies?

Comment: If you use a monitoring system like Zabbix or Nagios, there's a configurable interval for data rentation. For all data, it used to be a few weeks / months, and for trends, years.